# FlipSwitch style in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I would like to create a checkbox that looks like flipswitch. 
I used this CSS classes. and I used this design elements. But I could not succeded. There is something that i missed. I do not know how to manage that?

**Codes in XPages:**

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
 <xp:checkBox text="Label" id="onoffswitch"
    defaultChecked="true">

 <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>   <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
     </xp:checkBox>
</div>
```

**CSS Class: Resources\Style Sheets**

```
 .onoffswitch {
        position: relative; width: 90px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label {
        display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner {
        display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before {
        content: "ON";
        padding-left: 10px;
        background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        content: "OFF";
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .onoffswitch-switch {
        display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        right: 56px;
        border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
        right: 0px; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that when you need to put markup inside a control it mostly won't work because the XPages rendering will change or ignore it. To get around this I use plain markup with a hidden control located outside of the markup. I manage the state of the hidden control with JQuery.

Here is a working example for your FlipSwitch:

```
<xp:checkBox text="Label" id="checkBox1"></xp:checkBox>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" 
          onclick="x$('#{id:checkBox1}').prop('checked',  !(x$('#{id:checkBox1}').prop('checked'))    )" />
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

The `x$()` function is a handly utility from Mark Roden:

```
function x$(idTag, param){ //Updated 18 Feb 2012
   idTag=idTag.replace(/:/gi, "\\:")+(param ? param : "");
   return($("#"+idTag));
}
```